# Java.ArrayList. method remove()

Tags: java, arraylist

ArrayList have metod `remove(int index)` and `remove(Object o)`, so

i try run this code:
public static void main(String args[]){

```
    ArrayList<Long>ar=new ArrayList<Long>();

    ar.add(11L);
    ar.add(22L);
    ar.add(33L);

    ar.remove(new Integer(33)); // 1

    byte b =0;
    ar.remove(b);  //2

    for(Iterator i=ar.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
    {
        System.out.println(i.next());

    }

}
```

in result i have:

```
22
33
```

My question:

1. in line 1 parameter Integer - why we not have exception?
2. line 2 - paramenet byte - its not int and not Object, why not Exception again?

Comment: so, if i correctly understand for line 1 we have this situation: in our list we have Long, so when we try run remove method we have this: If(Integer.equals(Long)) returns false, our list not modified.

Comment: and next. byte -> int. its correct. but if i do this: long b =4654654654654654654L; long to int - imposible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The `remove(..)` method is not generic. It accepts any object and does not check its class. The condition it should meed in order for an element to be remove is the `equals(..)` method to return true when compared to an element in the collection. The element 33 is not removed, because `Long.equals(..)` returns `false` if the other object is not `instanceof Long`
2. the `byte` is interpreted as the index.

Comment: Actually the correct answer to part 2 of the question is that Java is Autoboxing the `byte` primative as a `java.lang.Byte` object and calling `ArrayList.remove(Object)`.

   57: aload_1
   58: iload_2
   59: invokevirtual #15; //Method java/util/ArrayList.remove:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: That was my initial answer. But it is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Because both of those get cast to the correct type. In the first one, it is remove(Object o) where o is Integer(33). But it dooesn't find that object in your arraylist, so it returns false as per the definiton:

> Returns:
>       true if this list contained the specified element.

The second probably gets cast to an int so you're removing the first index.

Answer (score 1):

1) You pass an object that is not in the list. So nothing happens.

2) It is not a object that is passed, but an index (0). So the first element in the arraylist is removed.

Comment: Wrong for #1: remove(Object) is called, and that does nothing if the element is not part of the list. remove(int) throws an exception if the index is out of bounds.

Comment: Still wrong. `Nothing happens` isn't quite right, it returns false.

Comment: Okok. but nothing happens to the list. That was the question.

Answer (score 1):

Java has built in autoboxing to save you the time of typecasting various numeric representations. No error because Java figures out what you meant and converts it for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Integer is being converted to an Object and thus does not throw an exception.
2. I reckon the byte is being converted to an int and is being treated as index 0 thus removing the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the javadocs. ArrayList.remove takes an Object and an Integer is is an Object.

[update] forgot to answer the second question.

The byte works because I believe it is  either [autoboxed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) into an Object or else it is upcast to an int as an index.